# Get XML String in PHP with URL

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, xml, url

I'm really new to the job as a web developer and I have a Problem that I cant solve alone, also I can't find any answers which fit my Problem.

So this is the Construct, I have a PHP Page with this Code:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://myserver.de/list.aspx';
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($url);
$name =  $xml->List->member->name;
?>
```

And I got this C#-Code from an aspx-project (list.aspx):

```
        StringBuilder xmlBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        xmlBuilder.Append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>");
        xmlBuilder.Append("<List>");
        foreach (var nameandplz in fullname.Zip(plz, Tuple.Create))
        {
            xmlBuilder.Append("<member>");
            xmlBuilder.Append("<name>" + nameandplz.Item1 + "</name>");
            xmlBuilder.Append("<postcalcode>" + nameandplz.Item2 + "</postalcode>");
            xmlBuilder.Append("</member>");
        }
        xmlBuilder.Append("</List>");
        Context.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
Context.Response.BinaryWrite(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlBuilder.ToString()));
        Context.Response.End();
```

So I just use the `StringBuilder` to build a String with XML.

**fullname** and plz are listed.

In my PHP-CIde i call the URL and the Problem is that the SimpleXMLElement doesnt write the XML-Code into the $xml.

I tried everything, i called the URL manually and the XML File is displayed correctly.

Do I use the wrong format to get the XML File per SimpleXMLElement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the data from the URL you must set $data_is_url = true according to the PHP Documentation ( http://php.net/manual/fr/simplexmlelement.construct.php ); so XMLElement try to build an XML from the string given.
You can use the function libxml_get_errors to get XML errors.

So here a code that will get the content from the URL :

```
<?php
$url = 'http://myserver.de/list.aspx';
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($url, 0, true);
$name =  $xml->List->member->name;
```

Caution : you access List / Member / Name without testing if List Member or Name exists.

Comment: You are right, I was missing the Parameters. Thank you! In my originalcode I'm testing the existence of the Membernames.